# How can i get only index name from response generated from elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, curl

How can i get only index name from response generated by calling `_cat/indices` using java. Using `EntityUtils` i am getting the response as string which gives me information in the way how it looks when called using CURL command. I am using rest low level client for fetching the response.

```
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

How should i process the responseBody to get only index name ?

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953617/how-to-get-all-indices-with-elastics-high-level-rest-client/51959593#51959593

Answer (score 0):

ClusterStateResponse response = client.admin().cluster().prepareState().execute().actionGet();

String[] indices = response.getState().getMetaData().getConcreteAllIndices();

You will get the list of indices.