# Elasticsearch Java Rest Client: how to get the list of all indices

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How do I get the list of all indices in Elasticsearch using the Rest Client?

(All answers I've found online seem to deal with the old type of client.

I fail to find the direct answer in the doc,

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/index.html

can't figure out which section to look into, either Cluster or Index APIs etc.)

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953617/how-to-get-all-indices-with-elastics-high-level-rest-client/51959593#51959593

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via the REST API you can verify with this URL : http://elasticsearch:9200/_cat/indices?v

Via the Java Client API (I just realised you asked this way) : you can bet on the Cluster Health API : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-cluster-health.html

And use

```
ClusterHealthRequest request = new ClusterHealthRequest();
ClusterHealthResponse response = client.cluster().health(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
Set<String> indices = response.getIndices().keySet();
```

And you will get the list of indices ;)

Answer (score 3):

In current Java High Level REST Client you can list all indices simply by requesting a [GetIndex request](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-get-index.html) with "*" as an index name.

```
GetIndexRequest request = new GetIndexRequest().indices("*");
GetIndexResponse response = client.indices().get(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
String[] indices = response.getIndices();
```